# Is visible spectroscopy the only non-electronic method of all the spectroscopy method?

Tags: spectroscopy

Is visible spectroscopy the only non-electronic method of all the spectroscopy method?

I know some of the spectroscopy method is possible being used because of electronics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Ultraviolet spectroscopy and Infra-red spectroscopy were practiced without any use of electricity.

Infra-red and ultraviolet light were both known by 1801.

Ultraviolet absorption lines had been observed by 1843.